# Existence of a large family of sets with big differences

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, cardinal-arithmetic

Let $\lambda\leq\kappa$ be two cardinals and $\Gamma$ be a set with $|\Gamma|=\kappa$.

> **Question.** Does there exist a family $\mathscr{A}\subseteq \{A\subseteq \Gamma: |A|=\lambda\}$ with $|\mathscr{A}|=\kappa^\lambda$ and such that
> $$
> |\,A_0 \setminus (A_1\cup\dots\cup A_n)|=\lambda\,\,\,
> \text{ for all distinct }A_0,\dots,A_n\in \mathscr{A}?
> $$

We would like to know whether the answer is affirmative for all cardinals $\lambda\le \kappa$. We know that the answer is affirmative in the following cases:

- $\kappa=\kappa^\lambda$ (take a partition of $\Gamma$ into $\kappa$ disjoint sets of size $\lambda$);
- $\lambda$ is the least cardinal with $\kappa<\kappa ^\lambda$ (in this case, it is possible to build an almost-disjoint family which satisfies the claim);
- $\lambda=\kappa$ (take an independent family of size $2^\kappa$; a somehow related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365807/intersection-number-of-a-cardinal)).

If it is a known fact, a reference would be appreciated.